# reasons for STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION for a user mode call in ntdll.dll library function

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, kernel

Is it possible to access functions on ntdll.dll from user mode? I used `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` to obtain function address of `NtOpenFile()` successfully. But I get `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` error during the call to `NtOpenFile`. I know that this would be because of memory related issues. Should I allocate memory virtually for the `UNICODE_STRING` structure? I am new to WinApi programming. I am using the example from [here](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/calling-ntdll-functions-directly/#gref)

```
int main() {
    typedef NTSTATUS(__stdcall* NT_OPEN_FILE)(OUT PHANDLE FileHandle, IN ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess, IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes, OUT PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock, IN ULONG ShareAccess, IN ULONG OpenOptions);
    NT_OPEN_FILE NtOpenFileStruct;

    /* load the ntdll.dll */
    PVOID Info;
    HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(L"ntdll.dll");
    NtOpenFileStruct = (NT_OPEN_FILE)GetProcAddress(hModule, "NtOpenFile");
    if (NtOpenFileStruct == NULL) {
        printf("Error: could not find the function NtOpenFile in library ntdll.dll.");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("NtOpenFile is located at 0x%08x in ntdll.dll.\n", (unsigned int)NtOpenFileStruct);

    /* create the string in the right format */
    UNICODE_STRING filename;
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&filename, L"C:\\temp.txt" );
    /* initialize OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES */
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES obja;
    InitializeObjectAttributes(&obja, &filename, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, NULL, NULL);

    /* call NtOpenFile */
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iostatusblock;
    HANDLE file = NULL;
    NTSTATUS stat = NtOpenFileStruct(&file, FILE_WRITE_DATA, &obja, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (NT_SUCCESS(stat)) {
        printf("File successfully opened.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("File could not be opened.\n");
    }
    printf("Error = %x", stat);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have lots of opportunities to explore undefined behavior when using the Windows API. No need to drop down to the Native API. As for this question: Stack Overflow promotes the idea to have a single question per question posted.

Comment: and pointer to `&iostatusblock` your forget pass. and you not need `GetProcAddress` simply call `NtOpenFile` as is

Comment: note: NtOpenFileStruct is not a struct so I'm not sure why you called it Struct

Comment: Is it possible that you are passing it invalid parameters?

Comment: @RbMm i am trying to implement NtQueryLicenseValue() undocumented api , so i am using NtOpenFile() to study the behaviour of accessing the function pointer here.

Comment: NtOpenFileStruct(&file, FILE_WRITE_DATA, &obja, **NULL**, NULL, NULL); -  Pointer to an `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` mandatory parameter. i already not speak about invalid name format, etc. and anyway you not need `GetProcAddress`

Comment: @Mohan Why would you even think of this for simply using NtQueryLicenseValue? This function is present since VISTA and no need to search for it. Nevertheless, you could use GetProcAddress. Also that article of yours, is complete rubbish. You don't "call ntdll functions directly" like that, so don't follow that article.

Answer (score 0):

As comment pointed out, you need to pass a pointer of `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` (`&iostatusblock`) to the 4rd parameter.

```
NTSTATUS stat = NtOpenFileStruct(&file, FILE_WRITE_DATA, &obja, &iostatusblock, NULL, NULL);
```

Then, the sample will still get the error `STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_SYNTAX_BAD`(0xC000003B): The object path component was not a directory object.

Use Path like `L"\\??\\C:\\temp.txt` instead.

Comment: Hi, @Mohan, does this answer your question? Please feel free to let me know if you have any issue and also accept it if it does help.